# REST API calls are always cached

Tags: 9

In Drupal 9.2.6 I have a caching issue.

The code I am using is the following.

```php
$returnValues = [
  'value' => 'test',
  'time' => time(),
];

$response = new ResourceResponse($returnValues, 200, []);
$disable_cache = new CacheableMetadata();
$disable_cache->setCacheMaxAge(0);
$response->addCacheableDependency($disable_cache);
return $response;
```

This leads to this error.

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\ChainEncoder::getEncoder() must be of the type string, null given, called in /webspace/public/vendor/symfony/serializer/Encoder/ChainEncoder.php on line 49 in Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\ChainEncoder->getEncoder() (Zeile 80 in /webspace/public/vendor/symfony/serializer/Encoder/ChainEncoder.php)

This is also doesn't work.

```php
$response = new ResourceResponse($returnValues);
$response->addCacheableDependency($returnValues);
return $response;
```

What's wrong?

Comment: So you don't want it cached? But you are adding a cacheable dependency? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182863/rest-get-without-caching

Comment: @apaderno This is also cached:
$response = new Response();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->setContent(json_encode($returnValues));
    return $response;

Comment: This Question likely has some valid Answers: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/182863/10645

Comment: I don't know why - but today it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Drupal\rest\ModifiedResourceResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21ModifiedResourceResponse.php/class/ModifiedResourceResponse/9.0.x) instead of ResourceResponse, then it won't be cached.